# Modifying a bipartite graph so that it would have a perfect matching

Tags: graph-algorithm, matching, bipartite

Given a bipartite graph with equal-sized sides X and Y, how can we efficiently find the minimum number of edges we have to add so that the graph will have a perfect matching? is there a better solution than iterating over all 2^(|X|) subsets and adding edges until Hall's theorem is satisfied?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understood the question correctly, it should be possible to generate a [cardinality-maximal](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matching_(graph_theory)) matching of the initial graph efficiently, by either using the so-called [Hungarian method](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hungarian_algorithm) or modelization as a network flow problem. Once the cardinality-maximal matching has been found, there must be an equal number of unmatched nodes in either partition, which can be matched using additional edges at will.

In other words, if `M` is the cardinality of a cardinality-maximal matching in the original graph and `|X|=|Y|` holds, then at at least `M-|X|` edges have to be added in order to have a perfect matching contained in the graph.